# How can I efficiently store large number sequences in a SQL db?

Tags: sql, list, sqlite, relational-database, sequence

I want to store some number sequences in my database. So I:

```
+-----+---------+-----+
| idx | seq_id  | x   |
+-----+---------+-----+
|   1 |       1 |   1 |
|   2 |       1 |   1 |
|   3 |       1 |   2 |
|   4 |       1 |   3 |
|   5 |       1 |   5 |
|   6 |       1 |   7 |
|   1 |       2 |   1 |
|   2 |       2 |   2 |
|   3 |       2 |   4 |
|   4 |       2 |   8 |
|   5 |       2 |  16 |
|         ...         |
+-----+---------+-----+
```

but when I look at it, it feels like I'm storing more overhead with `idx` and `seq_id` than meaningful information.

In some sense I am, but I wouldn't find strange if the database engine optimized most of the repetition here. Is this the case for **SQLite**, MySQL, Postgre...?

And what can I make, perhaps in terms of table definition, to help the db optimize this storage pattern?

Comment: AFAIK the database won't optimize out repetitive data.  And please stop using `teh` for `the`.

Comment: May I most-kindly put it to you this way?  **"Is *the computer* *actually(!) complaining'* here, or you merely grousing that *you think it 'should' be?"*** If you are not **"compelled, by the *hardware,"*** to think about 'optimization' and/or 'efficiency,' then: *"please, don't borrow trouble."* (JM2CW ... but, after many decades.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson, I just want to know if SQLite and similar databases are reasonable for this storage pattern. If they are not, I will consider better alternatives.

Comment: Like I said: "is **the computer** *forcing(!)* you to conclude: "woe is me, it is not?" **Unless(!)** the answer is clearly-and-unavoidably *'yes,'*IMHO  simply allow the computer to excel at the things which it does best, and find other things with which to preoccupy your time.

Comment: Why do you want to store these sequences? How will you use them? You haven't explained what your goal is apart from "store these sequences". Presumably you want to access them again at some point. In what way? How fast?

Comment: @Blorgbeard my most common access pattern will be: slurp a range of some sequence into memory and do some operations. I will need to update teh db too, but not often.